# Can´t reach table after add subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
TT.TAXAMOUNTCUR,
TT.TAXORIGIN,
TT.VOUCHER,
TT.TAXITEMGROUP,
TT.TAXCODE,
TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,
TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
GJAERIVA.TEXT,
GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE,
GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71,41) 
AND TT.TRANSDATE <= '"+ @[User::fecha] +"'
WHERE   
(TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN  '"+ @[User::fecha_ini] +"' AND  '"+ @[User::fecha] +"') OR (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '"+ @[User::fecha_ini] +"' AND  '"+@[User::fecha] +"' )) AS T
```

And it works perfect

But now after end of it I want to set a left merge join with `TT` who is my table, so my query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
TT.TAXAMOUNTCUR,
TT.TAXORIGIN,
TT.VOUCHER,
TT.TAXITEMGROUP,
TT.TAXCODE,
TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,
TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
GJAERIVA.TEXT,
GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE,
GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71,41) 
AND TT.TRANSDATE <= '"+ @[User::fecha] +"'
WHERE   
(TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN  '"+ @[User::fecha_ini] +"' AND  '"+ @[User::fecha] +"') OR (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '"+ @[User::fecha_ini] +"' AND  '"+@[User::fecha] +"' )) AS T

   --JOIN 


     LEFT MERGE JOIN 
  (SELECT VOUCHER,SOURCERECID,TAXITEMGROUP,TAXCODE,GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,TAXAMOUNT,TAXAMOUNTCUR FROM TT) TTRISR ON TT.VOUCHER = TTRISR.VOUCHER AND TT.SOURCERECID = TTRISR.SOURCERECID 
  AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRISR.TAXITEMGROUP 
  AND (TTRISR.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%')
  AND TTRISR.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

But I get an issue:

> Invalid object name TT.

Comment: It no works, I´mgetting same issue @JonEkiz

Comment: oh ok. i missed that it's a subquery and you are trying to left join to that subquery. in the outer query, there is no more TT. will post an answer soon.

Comment: You can put the subquery in a WITH CTE statement and then do the self join I guess.

Comment: The subquery is aliased `as T`. Do you mean to join `T`, not `TT`?

Comment: I have `FROM TT` in subquery.  `TT` is `TAXTRANS` Table I have in my fist select @HABO

Comment: Yes, `FROM TAXTRANS TT` is _in_ the subquery, but the _result_ of the subquery is `as T` and available for joining or other uses. The scope of `TT` is limited to the subquery, although `TAXTRANS` is still available and, for maximum confusion, you could reference the same table _with the same alias_ again. Not  a best practice.

Comment: So, what should I do to insert thay subquery? because I need to use registers of TAXTRANS I have in my first select @HABO

Comment: If you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would help us help you. It is difficult to tell whether you simply need to reference `T` and `TAXTRANS` to solve your problem, whether a common table expression (CTE) as suggested by Jon Ekiz to allow multiple references to your subquery would help, or perhaps something else. [This](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) has some additional tips for writing good database questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first derived table (subquery) is given the alias T, so when joining the second derived table use T not TT

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            TT.TAXAMOUNTCUR , TT.TAXORIGIN , TT.VOUCHER , TT.TAXITEMGROUP
          , TT.TAXCODE , TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR , TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR
          , TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP
          , TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
          , TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION
          , GJAERIVA.TEXT
          , GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE
          , GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
      FROM TAXTRANS TT
      INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
      INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID
            AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN (14, 236, 71, 41)
            AND TT.TRANSDATE <= '"+ @[User::fecha] +"'
      WHERE (TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11
      AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '"+ @[User::fecha_ini] +"' AND '"+ @[User::fecha] +"')
      OR (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11
      AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '"+ @[User::fecha_ini] +"' AND '"+@[User::fecha] +"')
    ) AS T
LEFT MERGE JOIN (
      SELECT
            VOUCHER , SOURCERECID , TAXITEMGROUP , TAXCODE
          , GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY , TAXAMOUNT , TAXAMOUNTCUR
      FROM TT
    ) TTRISR ON T.VOUCHER = TTRISR.VOUCHER
          AND T.SOURCERECID = TTRISR.SOURCERECID
          AND T.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRISR.TAXITEMGROUP
          AND (TTRISR.TAXCODE LIKE 'RISR%')
          AND TTRISR.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```